# Problem parsing piped command streams in python, need help

Tags: bash, python

Wanted to convert my bash script to python.  The script

```
sensors | grep "Core"
```

Returns a nice output easily parsed, one line for each core of the CPU and if read into an array using

```
IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< "$line"
T="${array[2]}"
U="${T:1:-2}"
```

The desired temperature is the second element in the array and it is easy (somewhat) to remove the "+" and the trailing  centigrade symbol as shown in above code.

Tried doing this in python with the following code

```
all_temps = check_output(["sensors"])
exe = Popen(['grep', 'Core'],stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE);
cpu_temps = exe.communicate(input=all_temps)[0];
```

The difficulty for me is that the data in cpu_temps is a bunch of ascii bytes including special codes.  I thought I could easily split the data using new line as a delimiter to get one line for each cpu and then split using white space to pick up the current temp value.  This should have worked and was basically how my bash script worked.  I also handled "nvidia-smi" the same way and also pulled the ATI temps out of sensors the same way.  Just do not see how to do it in python.  The problem:

```
print(cpu_temps.split()) ---
b'Core'
b'0:'
b'+42.0\xc2\xb0C'
b'(high'
b'='
b'+84.0\xc2\xb0C,'
b'crit'
b'='
b'+100.0\xc2\xb0C)'
b'Core'
```

I am not sure what I am looking at in the above and have even less of an inkling on how to extract each core# and the corresponding value.  Probably going about this all wrong or should have stuck with my bash script.  When I try to split I start getting errors that str was expected and I had bytes.

Comment: You're looking at the unicode [degree sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm)

Comment: Yea, know that. What is the significance of the "b". There are 36 entries in the above: 4 cores and 9 elements in the array. Not obvious what to do but item 2 can get me the 42.0 but is it a string? Byte array?   I tried putting '\n' into the split() and it was rejected with error about string not expected

Comment: As you already decided to write Python, use its native text processing capabilities (string functions, `re` module for regex matching, ...) to parse the `sensors` output, instead of trying to spawn an external `grep` process for basic filtering.

Comment: Yes. When I suggested you do it in python, it was because you said you were already using python, so using its far superior text processing capabilities. If all you want is to get the number, just do `sensors | grep -oP 'Core.+?\+\K[\d.]+'`. Or, just explain what your final objective is, what exactly you are trying to do, but without the specifics of how you've tried to do it so far. I get the feeling there's a much simpler way.

Comment: Posted answer the way I would do it. Sorry but have no clue about your methodology and how to fix it. Plus I can't even test your script because it's not posted....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm in the same boat sailing from Bash Basin to Python Peninsula. I had to use a series of `xrandr` and `wmctrl` commands piped through `grep` for my inaugural project (still on-going *sigh*). Your solution would be:

```python
$ sensors | grep Core
Core 0:        +47.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +49.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +45.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +47.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

```python
$ sensors.py
49
51
47
48
```

Here's your script:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
list_cores = os.popen("sensors | grep Core").read().splitlines()

for l in list_cores:

    # Core 0:        +47.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)  <---- sample
    #                ^  ^
    #                |  |
    #                |  +---- 2md split on decimal take [0] element (b list)
    #                +------- 1st aplit on plus sign take [1] element (a list)

    a = l.split("+") 
    b = a[1].split(".")
    c = b[0]
    print (c)
```

Mark as executable before running: `chmod a+x sensors.py`

Happy to answer any questions :)

Comment: Thanks, would not have know to use os.popen nor even how to lookup features.  I am using python3 and have found that a lot of examples don't work.  When I get my app working it will be on GitHub.  I am using it to send temperature information from Linux systems to BoincTasks which only handles windows temps.

Comment: Please confirm if it works with Python 3 if not I'll adjust code.

Comment: Works fine with 3 no problem. I am beginner in python and the WiKi geared for beginners seem not to be updated much.  Some code shows no () in the print statement that are required and other show a single variable in an argument call but the newer python requires two args.  Some of these could  just be typos

Comment: I've been learning copying answers here and in stack overflow. Then I modify and debug.

Comment: Got my program working.  It is at github jstateson boinctasks.  The split at the decimal point loses the fractional part of the centigrade but it is not worth the effort to recover.  (I was unable to split using that deg cent character)

Comment: I thought you wanted to truncate the decimal. Split on the `C` instead. Then you get `51.0°
54.0°
53.0°
50.0°
`

Comment: Will try that!  Hopefully the conversion to float and back to string will drop the trailing special char.  I will look at deleting that last char also.  When using a "rule" in boinctasks to determine if temps are too high, it does not matter if it is 90 or 90.1 as a text message needs to be sent from BT if the threshold is reached.

Comment: Yes it could be you are better off with an integer comparison in the original format rather than having a float with the decimal point.